# Container with Content and sidebar

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a page with a container that contains the content, and a right sidebar. Whenever I enter content into the content into the sidebar or content div, it continues into the footer, and the sidebar sometimes moves to the left side of the page.

I feel like I have a Height issue somewhere. I want the container section to be as big as the content/sidebar takes up, but it seems to be overflowing into the footer rather than expanding the container.

Here is an exampe of what my HTML looks like:

```
    <body>
        <div class="MainContainer">
        <div class="RightSideBar">
          Sidebar Text
        </div> 

        <div class=MainContent>
            Content Text
        </div>

        </div>
    <footer>
        Footer Text
    </footer>
</body
```

And CSS

```
body{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

footer{
 height:20%;
 width:60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 color:white;
}
.RightSideBar{
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
  float:right;
}
.MainContent{
 width:80%;
 height: auto;  
}
```

Comment: add `clear:both;` with your footer css code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `overflow: hidden;` on the .MainContainer

Comment: Ok, I believe that worked. Is it possible to set the sidebar to the same as the container? If i set it to 100% of the container right now it takes a huge amount of space outside of the container, even with overflow:hidden

Comment: @Dylan try using the rule: `height: inherit;`, this should set the height of the `sidebar` to the height of the parent div (`.MainContainer.`)

Comment: I think that would work if I didn't have the height of the container set to auto.

Comment: @Dylan hmm.. try looking at the answer below that might solve it. Since I'm not very sure how to fix this.. (I always use Skeleton css (Frame Work) with rows, whose will automaticly be placed next to each other). Link: getskeleton.com/, you could take a look.. it's pretty useful!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `float`, if you know what sizes the elements are going to be, use `display:inline-block` instead.

Html:

```
<main>
  <div class="content col">articles..</div>
  <aside class="col">sidebar..</aside>
</main>
```

Css:

```
main {
   font-size:0;
}
.col {
   font-size:16px;
   display:inline-block;
}
.content {
   width:80%;
}
aside {
   width:20%;
}
```

Comment: They just seem to be sitting right on top of each other now.

Comment: @Dylan that's because of the white space created by the idents of the html tag's. I've added a fix for that to my answer.